# Linked lists and arrays

Tags: c

I have to make linked lists that contain all the non zero values from an array and print it out. However, my code is printing out the same value for how many non zero elements there are in the array.

The creation of the linked list and printing of the linked list are two separate functions.

The addLink function creates the linked list

```
void addlink(DataPtr *start, int element, double value) {
    Data last = *start;
    Data newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Data));
    newPtr->element = element;
    newPtr->usage = value;
    newPtr->next = NULL;

    if(*start == NULL) {
        *start = newPtr;
        return;
        newPtr->element = element;
        newPtr->usage = value;
        newPtr->next = NULL;
    }

    while(last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->nextPtr;
        last->next = newPtr;
        return;
    }
}
```

The print function prints the linked list

```
void print(Data *start) {
    Data current = *start;

    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->element);
        printf("%.3lf", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is how i call it in my main

```
    for(k = 0; k < 50; k++) {
        if(values[k] != 0) {
            value = values[k];
            addlink(&start,k,value);
            print(&start);
        }
    }


   struct data{
int element;
double value;
struct data *next;
   };
  typedef struct data Data;
  typedef Data *DataPtr;

  DataPtr start = NULL;
```

Comment: What does this Data newPtr;

newPtr = (DataPtr)malloc(sizeof(Data));

 mean? On the one hand, newPtr has type Data, on the other hand there is used casting ( DataPtr).

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow is correct, and also in main, what is declaration of `start` variable?

Comment: @mellow  And why is newPtr at first allocated newPtr = (DataPtr)malloc(sizeof(Data)); and then freed free(newPtr);?

Comment: Aren't you getting compiler warnings when you try to assign a pointer to `Data`?

Comment: @CoreyLakey Data start = NULL;

Comment: @Barmar i do not get any errors

Comment: What does the `Data` typedef look like? In general, try to avoid using typedef for pointers, it gets confusing.

Comment: What's DataPtr? What's Data? Ot looks like Data is a pointer type, in which case `malloc(sizeof(Data))` is very likely wrong.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(sometype))` should be assigned to a variable of `sometype *`.

Comment: How else would he make linked list without pointers to the types of list items he creates? @Barmar or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @CoreyLakey You generally have a `Node` type, and then use `Node *node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));`

Comment: Post more code @mellow, let us see the structures, and declarations. Doesn't look like you have much since you're just creating the list here and getting errors.. let's see the rest.

Comment: struct data
{
    int element;
    double value;
    struct data *next;
};
typedef struct data Data;
typedef Data *DataPtr;

Comment: No @mellow post it in your original post and make it look readable.

Comment: @Barmar, I had mistunderstood, I agree with you.

Comment: @mellow The code shall not compile.

Comment: @mellow Show also the declaration of start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct implementation of your list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data {
    int element;
    double value;
    struct data *next;
} data_t;


void print(data_t *start);
void addlink(data_t **start, int element, double value);

int main()
{
    int values[50] = { 0 };
    int value = 0;
    int k;
    data_t *start = NULL;

    //Give values some value
    values[0] = 100;
    values[1] = 250;

    for(k = 0; k < 50; k++)
    {
        if(values[k] != 0)
        {
            value = values[k];
            addlink(&start,k,value);
            print(start);
        }
    }
}

void addlink(data_t **start, int element, double value)
{
    data_t *newPtr;

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(data_t));

    newPtr->element = element;
    newPtr->value = value;
    *start = newPtr;

}
void print(data_t *start)
{
    data_t *current = start;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", current->element);
        printf("%f", current->value);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Your DataPtr idea, is no good. The "data_t" implementation is generally what you will see when seeing linked lists. It is easiest implemented this way.

If you are trying to implement a list that adds the newest data_t to the end of the list...

Check out http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A correct function implementation can look the following way

```
int addlink( DataPtr *start, int element, double value ) 
{
    DataPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Data));
    int success = newPtr != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newPtr->element = element;
        newPtr->value = value;
        newPtr->next = NULL;

        while ( *start != NULL ) start = &( *start )->next;

        *start = newPtr;
    }

    return success;
}
```

If you want to add new elements at the beginning of the list then the function can look like

```
int addlink( DataPtr *start, int element, double value ) 
{
    DataPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Data));
    int success = newPtr != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newPtr->element = element;
        newPtr->value = value;
        newPtr->next = *start;

        *start = newPtr;
    }

    return success;
}
```

As for showed by you the function implementation then it shall not even compile. For example in this code snippet

```
Data last = *start;
Data newPtr;

newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Data));
```

the expression `*start` has the type `DataPtr` while the initialized variable `last` has the type `Data`. The same problem exists for the variable `newPtr`.

The function `print` can look like

```
void print( DataPtr *start ) 
{
    for ( DataPtr current = *start; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf("%d ", current->element);
        printf("%.3lf", current->value);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

And it is called like

```
print( &start );
```

Comment: Your addlink wouldn't work since there is no `usage` member of his struct.

Comment: @CoreyLakey I have not understood what you mean. The shown code if it does not contain a typo is correct.

Comment: If the struct contains a member called `usage` it is. Also please guide mellow away from the `typedef DataPtr *data;` idea. It is too confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: @CoreyLakey I just copied and pasted this statement from his code. He changed his code several times. But in any case it is not important.

Comment: he hadn't changed that part. But I will say most would find it important to guide a beginner away from a struct that is just used to create a pointer of another struct, rather than simply using `*`. Picking up what I am putting down? :)

Comment: @CoreyLakey See its function definition. There is statement newPtr->usage = value;.